# Run a sql query on a PySpark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am using Databricks and I already have loaded some DataTables.

However, I have a complex SQL query that I want to operate on these data tables, and I wonder if i could avoid translating it in pyspark.

Is that possible?

To give an example:

In SQL:

```
with table2 as (
   select column1, column1
   from database.table1
   where
         start_date <= DATE '2019-03-01' and
         end_date >= DATE '2019-03-31'            )
```

In pyspark I would already have `table1` loaded but the following does not work because it can not find `table1`.

```
query = "(
    select column1, column1
           from table1
               where
         start_date <= DATE '2019-03-01' and
         end_date >= DATE '2019-03-31'            )"
table2 = spark.sql(query)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you register it as temp table in pyspark? or it is from Hive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try giving `databasename.tablename` instead of `tablename` in query.

```
query = "(
    select column1, column1
           from *database_name.table_name* 
               where
         start_date <= DATE '2019-03-01' and
         end_date >= DATE '2019-03-31' )"
```

If you are using `pyspark` then it must be

```
spark.sql(query)
```

Comment: does not work, the query is not even valid python string.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP said to assume that a DataFrame `table1` exists in the Python session. Your response just queries a database table.

Answer (score 0):

- After Spark 3.4, `SparkSession.sql` supports [parameterized SQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql.html). So you can just make it like this:

```py
# spark -> your SparkSession object

table1 = spark.sql('''
select column1, column1
from database.table1
where
    start_date <= DATE '2019-03-01' 
    and end_date >= DATE '2019-03-31'
'''
)

# just reference table1 as keyword argument of `.sql` function.
table2 = spark.sql('''
select column1, column1
from {tb}
    where start_date <= DATE '2019-03-01' 
    and end_date >= DATE '2019-03-31'
''', tb=table1)
```

- Before Spark 3.4, it's a little more complicated, but also quite easy:

```py
table1 = spark.sql('''
select column1, column1
from database.table1
where
    start_date <= DATE '2019-03-01' 
    and end_date >= DATE '2019-03-31'
'''
)

# create a temporary view
table1.createOrReplaceTempView('view_table1')

# now you can reference to the view by name
table2 = spark.sql('''
select column1, column1
from view_table1
    where start_date <= DATE '2019-03-01' 
    and end_date >= DATE '2019-03-31'
''')
```